# Replace the linear layout with a fragment issue in Android

Tags: android, fragment

I have a few drawer items in the navigation drawer. When the first item(Motels) is clicked it goes to an activity that has a list of motels. Each of them is wrapped in cardView. I have implemented the click for the cardView and when it is clicked it should replace the linear layout with a fragment. But it is unresponsive.
Here it is the code:
Motels.java(Activity that contains the list of motels):

```
package com.example.sabudaniel61.ktdc;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;



/**
 * Created by Jobin Sabu on 1/11/2016.
 */
public class Motels extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.motels);

        CardView cardView1=(CardView) findViewById(R.id.cardView1);
        cardView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                MotelKttrk motelKttrk = new MotelKttrk();
                transaction.replace(R.id.linearmotel, motelKttrk);
                transaction.commit();


            }
        });
    }
}
```

motels.xml(Layout holding list of motels):
When one of the lists is clicked it should replace the LinearLayout with id @+id/linearmotel

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linearmotel">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="#1b5e20"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="KTDC MOTELS AT A GLANCE"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="25sp"></TextView>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/cardView1"
                app:cardElevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
                app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

                <com.andexert.library.RippleView
                    rv_centered="true"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="0dp"
                    app:rv_color="#b2dfdb">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linear1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:clickable="true">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="7dp"
                            android:layout_height="7dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                            android:background="#90000000" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:text="Motel Araam, Kottarakkara "

                            android:textSize="17sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </com.andexert.library.RippleView>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
                app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

                <com.andexert.library.RippleView
                    rv_centered="true"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    app:rv_color="#b2dfdb">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linear2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"


                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="7dp"
                            android:layout_height="7dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:background="#90000000" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:text="Motel Araam, Punaloor"
                            android:textSize="17sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </com.andexert.library.RippleView>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
                app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

                <com.andexert.library.RippleView
                    rv_centered="true"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    app:rv_color="#b2dfdb">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linear3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"


                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="7dp"
                            android:layout_height="7dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:background="#90000000" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:text="Motel Araam, Palaruvi "
                            android:textSize="17sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </com.andexert.library.RippleView>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
                app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

                <com.andexert.library.RippleView
                    rv_centered="true"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    app:rv_color="#b2dfdb">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linear4"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"


                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="7dp"
                            android:layout_height="7dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:background="#90000000" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:text="Motel Araam, Kayamkulam"
                            android:textSize="17sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </com.andexert.library.RippleView>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
                app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

                <com.andexert.library.RippleView
                    rv_centered="true"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    app:rv_color="#b2dfdb">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linear5"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"


                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="7dp"
                            android:layout_height="7dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:background="#90000000" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:text="Motel Araam, Alappuzha "
                            android:textSize="17sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </com.andexert.library.RippleView>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
                app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

                <com.andexert.library.RippleView
                    rv_centered="true"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    app:rv_color="#b2dfdb">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linear6"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"


                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="7dp"
                            android:layout_height="7dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:background="#90000000" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:text="Motel Araam, Vaikkom  "
                            android:textSize="17sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </com.andexert.library.RippleView>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
                app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

                <com.andexert.library.RippleView
                    rv_centered="true"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    app:rv_color="#b2dfdb">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linear7"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"


                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="7dp"
                            android:layout_height="7dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:background="#90000000" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:text="Motel Araam, Athirapally  "
                            android:textSize="17sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </com.andexert.library.RippleView>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
                app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

                <com.andexert.library.RippleView
                    rv_centered="true"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    app:rv_color="#b2dfdb">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linear8"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"


                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="7dp"
                            android:layout_height="7dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:background="#90000000" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:text="Motel Araam, Kuttipuram "
                            android:textSize="17sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </com.andexert.library.RippleView>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
                app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

                <com.andexert.library.RippleView
                    rv_centered="true"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    app:rv_color="#b2dfdb">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linear9"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"


                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="7dp"
                            android:layout_height="7dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:background="#90000000" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:text="Motel Araam, Erumayur "
                            android:textSize="17sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </com.andexert.library.RippleView>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            >

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
                app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

                <com.andexert.library.RippleView
                    rv_centered="true"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    app:rv_color="#b2dfdb">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linear10"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"


                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="7dp"
                            android:layout_height="7dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:background="#90000000" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:text="Motel Araam, Vadakara "
                            android:textSize="17sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </com.andexert.library.RippleView>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
                app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

                <com.andexert.library.RippleView
                    rv_centered="true"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    app:rv_color="#b2dfdb">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linear11"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="7dp"
                            android:layout_height="7dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:background="#90000000" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:text="Motel Aaram, Kannur"
                            android:textSize="17sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </com.andexert.library.RippleView>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


</LinearLayout></LinearLayout>
```

MotelKttrk.java(Fragment):

```
package com.example.sabudaniel61.ktdc;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by Jobin Sabu on 1/12/2016.
 */
public class MotelKttrk extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.motel_kottarakara,container,false);
        return v;
    }
}
```

motel_kottarakara.xml(Layout of fragment):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:id="@+id/motel1">

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:text="Motel Araam, Kottarakkara\n(Thiruvananthapuram-Kottayam MC road)"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="#F50057"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:layout_weight="0.03" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Located at 70 km from Thiruvananthapuram by the side of MC   Road in Kottarakkara, this motel facilitates a break for travellers begining their journey from Trivandrum.This motel is about 80 km from Kottayam ie. almost middle of Thiruvananthapuram - Kottayam MC road."
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:background="#ffffff"

        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_weight="0.03" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:text="Facilities"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:padding="14dp"

        android:textColor="#F50057"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_weight="0.03" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:text="Two non A/c twin bedded rooms\nA/c and Non A/c restaurants"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:background="#ffffff"


        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_weight="0.03" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your linearmotel from `LinearLayout` to `FrameLayout` in xml and define width and height.

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent" // change as per your requirement
        android:layout_height="match_parent" // change as per your requirement
        android:id="@+id/linearmotel">
```

Comment: I have implemented click to linearlayout with id R.id.linear1.It works but it is dispalyed as the screenshot above.The contents in the frame layout are not removed.

Comment: That happens because you used wrap_content property while defining the height of your container layout.